# Crypto-js decrypt is wrong

Tags: javascript, cryptojs

I am using crypto-js. I tried to check if the `IV` is working so I use different IV for encryption and decryption. But when I check the result the `console.log(decryptedPlaintext);` will still output the `Hello World`. It should not be because I am using different `IV` for decrypt. How to fix this?

```
        import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';

        const secretKey = 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY';
        const iv = 'YOUR_INITIALIZATION_VECTOR';
        const iv1 = 'YOUR_INITIALIZATION_RECTOR';

        const plaintext = 'Hello World';

        const ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plaintext, secretKey, {
          iv: iv,
          mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
          padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        }).toString();
        console.log(ciphertext); 

        const decryptedBytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, secretKey, {
          iv: iv1,
          mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
          padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        });

        const decryptedPlaintext = decryptedBytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
        console.log(decryptedPlaintext);
```

Comment: The result you're talking about is `console.log(ciphertext);`? Also, shouldn't you use the same `iv` for both encrypt and decrypt?

Comment: the ` console.log(decryptedPlaintext);` will still output the `Hello World` even I used different IV for decrypt

Comment: Well, isn't that what it's supposed to output? What's your expected result?

Comment: I expect the result to be wrong or some empty string because the IV is different. It is a threat.

Comment: Your IV is ignored since the built-in key derivation function is applied which derives key and IV (this is because the key material is passed as string, see the CryptoJS documentation).

Comment: @Topaco what is the correct way?this is not working either

`       const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("YOUR_INITIALIZATION_VECTOR");
        const iv1 = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("YOUR_INITIALIZATION_RECTOR");
`

Comment: @Topaco I've tested the code, and seems like `CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(16);` for generating the IV produces the correct results. Does that mean that any strings passed are ignored?

Comment: @JBA - *...what is the correct way...* If you want to pass key and IV *directly* (i.e. without key derivation), you must pass both as *WordArray*s.

Comment: @LightningMcQueen - The explicitly set IV is ignored, so you can pass any IV (even a random one). For the IV not to be ignored, the key must be passed as a `WordArray`.